# Chrome Debugger, console this value is different from local this value

Tags: javascript, typescript, this

just I am wondering if it is correct. See the images below.

[image]

LOCAL VALUE

[image]

CONSOLE

[image]

I'm in a lambda function and "this" should be the instance of the class I'am debugging. Instead in the console drawer the this value is equal to window even if the local value is the instance of the current object.

What I'am doing wrong ?

Tnks